# BIM360 Submittal API Documentation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

BIM360 Submittal API Documentation is no longer part of the public documentation.
What is the future for support of this API for BIM360 and ACC?

It was listed in this documentation but I noticed today it is no longer part of the documentation. https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/documentation

Answer (score 0):

BIM 360 Submittal API was never officially released. We have a wish about it, however:
DMINFRA-1031: “API Wish: expose Submittals API”

(There may be a case where the product team conducted a private testing. But for any official or public release, it must go through a release process which our team is a part of it. So we should know at least.)

Happy to add business case to the above wish if you would like. Feel free to send it to us through aps.help@autodesk.com.